# How to put multiple empheq environments side-by-side?

Tags: empheq

How do I put multiple `empheq` environments side-by-side? Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*}
&\frac{1}{n} > \frac{1}{n^2} \\
&{a'}^2 - \frac{2a'}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} > 2
\end{empheq}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*}
&\frac{1}{n} > \frac{1}{n^2} \\
&\frac{1 - 2a'}{n} > 2 - {a'}^2
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

but side-by-side and with a mandatory `\implies` between the environments.

Comment: I don't think you need `align*` nor `empheq`, as `cases` (requires `amsmath`) is sufficient.

Comment: @egreg, is it possible to insert braces on the left of equation systems using `cases`?

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of `cases`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with `dcases` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{dcases}
\frac{1}{n} > \frac{1}{n^2} \\[1ex]
a'^2 - \frac{2a'}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} > 2
\end{dcases}
\quad\implies\quad
\begin{dcases}
\frac{1}{n} > \frac{1}{n^2} \\[1ex]
\frac{1 - 2a'}{n} > 2 - a'^2
\end{dcases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! Any chance the brace can be lengthy enough to cover `1`s? I just don't particularly like the fact that they're above the brace.

Comment: @EgorTensin that's a feature of `dcases`, I guess, but I don't dislike it. Try with `cases`, but changing every `\frac` into `\dfrac` and `[1ex]` into `[2ex]`.

Comment: Ok, I just went with the regular `cases` environment, but with the fractions displayed in a lesser size. Could you please guide me on weather it's good style or not?

Comment: @EgorTensin As I said, use `\dfrac`

Comment: Yeah, it turned out to be ok with the fractions (as far as I understand) being typeset in "display style". The issue with the spacing though. There are no spacing issues with the regular `frac`s, I just thought it might be an example of bad style to typeset this way. Or isn't it? It looks more or less OK to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can roll your own in a number of ways. Here's one using an `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.1}% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764
  \left\{\begin{array}{l@{}}
    \dfrac{1}{n} > \dfrac{1}{n^2} \\
    {a'}^2 - \dfrac{2a'}{n} + \dfrac{1}{n^2} > 2
  \end{array}\right. \quad \implies \quad
  \left\{\begin{array}{l@{}}
    \dfrac{1}{n} > \dfrac{1}{n^2} \\
    \dfrac{1 - 2a'}{n} > 2 - {a'}^2
  \end{array}\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, not the first time you save my day! I'll try to stick to the ready-made solution using `mathtools` though.